# Is it possible to pass data from controller to kernel schedule?

Tags: php, laravel

I'm working on task scheduling to send sms notification to users at a specific date or time. Is it possible to pass data from controller to kernel schedule? Let's say:

```
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
{
    $schedule->command('sms:send')->dailyAt($time);
}
```

If it is possible, any tips on how to do it? Thank you very much.

Comment: I think you must create your own command and in the handel method you can get your wanted data ==> [read more](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/artisan#writing-commands)

Comment: Sorry for the late response. Thank you Maraboc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call controller to Console/Commands/Yourclass

like this in handle() function-

```
protected $signature = 'showing:rating'; //your command

//you can write and call logic here in handle function
public function handle()
{
    $rating = (new CronController())->showingRating();
}
```

And then you can call your command in Kernel@schedule() function like this -

```
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
{
    $schedule->command('showing:rating')
             ->hourly();
}
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Sorry for the late response. I don't quite understand  `$rating = (new CronController())->showingRating();` especially showingRating(). Anyway, thank you for your time.

Comment: CronController is my controller and showingRating() is a function which is defined in CronController. Here, i am calling showingRating()function which is in CronController.   $rating = (new CronController())->showingRating();

Comment: I see. I get it now. Thank you very much.